# How i can declare a global method in Oxygene

Tags: delphi-prism, oxygene

How i can [declare a global method in delphi prism](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Global_Class) using  the __Global class?

And It is recommended to use global methods?

unfortunately I have not found any example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can if you turn on the Allow Globals option in your project options. Then you can just do the following code:

```
interface

method GlobalMethod: Integer; public;

implementation
```

It is not recommended to use this construction. A more .Net way is to use a static/class method on a class.

```
type
  TSomeClass = public class
  public
    class method GlobalMethod: Integer;
  end;

// Call like this
I := TSomeClass.GlobalMethod;
```